# Set a value with multiple duplicate index in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a `DataFrame` with multiple duplicate index, my question is how can I set the value of row `A` in `col2` with value **0** to other value, say **8**.

#### Case 1:

```
In [82]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[9,9,0]}, index=['A','B','A'])

In [83]: df
Out[83]: 
   col1  col2
A     1     9
B     2     9
A     3     0
```

I know for this small and fixed `DataFrame` I can just use `ix` method with the desired position, as follow:

**Desired Result (3rd row change from `A 3 0` to `A 3 8`):**

```
In [84]: df.ix[2, 1] = 8                                                       

In [85]: df                                                                    
Out[85]:                                                                       
   col1  col2                                                                  
A     1     9                                                                  
B     2     9                                                                  
A     3     8
```

But for some large and changing DataFrame with multiple duplicate index, how can I set value of row `A` in `col2` with value **0** to other value?

#### Case 2:

```
In [90]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'col2':[9,9,0,9]}, index=['A','B','A','A'])

In [91]: df2                                                                 
Out[91]:                                                                    
   col1  col2                                                               
A     1     9                                                               
B     2     9                                                               
A     3     0                                                               
A     4     9
```

**Desired Result (3rd row change from `A 3 0` to `A 3 8`):**

```
In [91]: df2                                                                 
Out[91]:                                                                    
   col1  col2                                                               
A     1     9                                                               
B     2     9                                                               
A     3     8                                                               
A     4     9
```

#### Case 3:

```
In [94]: df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'col2':[9,9,0,0]}, index=['A','B','B','A'])

In [95]: df3                                                                
Out[95]:                                                                    
   col1  col2                                                               
A     1     9                                                               
B     2     9                                                               
B     3     0                                                               
A     4     0
```

**Desired Result (4th row change from `A 4 0` to `A 4 8`):**

```
In [95]: df3                                                                
Out[95]:                                                                    
   col1  col2                                                               
A     1     9                                                               
B     2     9                                                               
B     3     0                                                               
A     4     8
```

Comment: Can you explain what the desired result should be also it's poor form to increment your requirements, you should state up front what your full requirements are. This is because it wastes people's time answering a question with shifting goalposts

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for your advice. I just edit the text again, hope this can clarify the question I am asking.

Comment: Why isn't in case 3 the duplicated row b changed?

Comment: @EdChum This is just a toy example I made from a real problem that I encountered. I only want to change some specific duplicated index. E.g. in Case 3, I only want to change the index value with `A` in `col2` from `0` to `8`.

Comment: Do you know up front which specific index value you're looking for duplicates or not? Your question is fundamentally different from your original post

Comment: @EdChum Yes, I know which specific index value I am trying to change its value in `col2`. In these three cases, is `A` with value `0` in `col2`. And I think I get the solution from @Nader Hisham's answer. `df.loc[(df.index == 'A') & (df.col2 == 0), 'col2'] = 8` can solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.loc[(df.index == 'A') & (df.col2 == 0), 'col2'] = 8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this solution will change all the values in the row. E.g. from `A 3 0 ` to `A 8 8`

Comment: Yeah , don't you want to replace values in col2 with zero values and with index a to be any number ?

Comment: I just edit your answer, I think this is the solution I am looking for: `df.loc[(df.index == 'A') & (df.col2 == 0), 'col2'] = 8`.

Comment: ok , I just forgot to add `col2` it should be working fine now